# Items in div not staying in position

Tags: html, css

I Created a menu div. In this div, I want to add a couple of list items and a logo on the left. 
But, for example, when I give the menu items a padding or a height, they go outside the menu div like shown in the js fiddle. The items should not go outside their parent.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c6tp9zmx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use floated element instead of margin you given to the menu element

```
#logo {
    height:50px;
    width:80px;
    background-color:red;
    float:left; // add this
}
#menu ul {
    // margin-left:70%; // remove this
    float:right; // add this
    position: relative;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c6tp9zmx/1/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `height:100px;` from `#menu` to make it automatically expand to your list size. You could set a `min-height` instead. Also, give your list items more appropriate values for `margin` and `line-height` and add a `float:left;` to `#logo` if it should stay on the same horizontal axis as the list items.